# Lazy Loading Subquery Result - LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am building a system to load a large amount of data from a database and display them to the user in a grid. I'd like to make the query as efficient as possible, and wanted to know if lazy-loading a subquery was possible.

For example, I have a query resembling the following:

```cs
List<Result> = db.Entity1
    .Select(e1 => new RowVm {
        Id = e1.Id,
        SubqueryCount = db.Entity2.Where(e2 => e2.e1Id == e1.Id).Count(),
        OtherSubquery = db.Entity3.Where(e3 => e3.Name == e1.Name).ToList()
    })
    .Where(row => row.SubqueryCount > 10)
    .ToList();
```

My issue is, I would like `OtherSubquery` to delay loading until after the `.Where(row => row.SubqueryCount > 10)` because the number of entities will then be way fewer, reducing the computation required.

Crucially, however, my actual query has a dynamic filter instead of the static where clause above. This means I do not know which subqueries will need to be used to evaluate the filter, and hence moving the unused subqueries to a second select after the filter is not an option. The actual query also has many more subqueries (for different columns in the grid) so the performance difference would be rather large, I imagine.

Is this form of delaying execution of a subquery possible in LINQ, or do I just have to settle for the slower performance of loading all the subqueries in advance of filtering?

Comment: There is no subqueries, there is Eager Loading. You are loading collection as property. Try `AsSplitQuery` it will speedup loading. For such `custom` lazy load, it should be at least property which executes query again.

Comment: "the number of entities will then be way fewer, reducing the computation required" - are you sure about this? The whole query is executed on the DB, and though I'm no expert on execution plans, I think you need to take a look at the execution plan for the SQL (?) query this generates. I'm not convinced restrucutring your LINQ query will improve what work the database has to perform (for this example).

Comment: You should start using navigation properties: `db.Entity1.Entity2s.Count()`. Then you should move the predicates to the main Where: `Where(e1 => e1.Entity2s.Count() > 10).Select(e1 => new RowVm { ... SubqueryCount = e1.Entity2s.Count() }`. That makes it much easier to build the predicates and it doesn't make a difference for the generated query / query optimizer. In query syntax you could use the `let` keyword.